# Why does downsampling improve acccuracy? (UNet)

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I am trying to understand why my UNet replica model has lower accuracy when I did not downsample at all (Only changing the number of channels throughout the network) compare to when I use maxpooling layer like the original UNet.

Does downsample increase accuracy in general? If so why? Because I thought downsampling would actually reduce the accuracy since you're losing some information of the image.

Comment: Downsample the photo resolution?

Comment: Yes, downsample the photo/input resolution. On original UNet they downsample by using maxpooling 4 times. The size changed from 577 -> 32. However, in my testing I tried UNet without changing the input size (no downsample) meaning it's 577 throughout the network but got lower accuracy (test and validation around 10% lower). I'm wondering why this is the case?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. That’s worth including in the original question, as downsampling here (as opposed to in signal processing circles) is more likely to be interpreted as removing members of the majority class in order to balance the class ratio in a classification problem. (Statisticians dislike this approach, but people still do it and promote it.)