# Is downsampling necessary in CNN?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, pooling, transposed-convolution

I am still trying to understand the effect of any downsampling (reducing the input height and weight by 2 for example) by pooling or strided convolution? Does downsampling improve accuracy?

Because in my experiment with UNet model, 1 original UNet with downsampling and upsampling, and 1 without downsampling (original height and width are maintained throughout the network), the accuracy is a lot better with downsampling. Thanks!

Comment: How is this different from your [other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/589623/247274)?

Comment: This is more of general CNN question but the other specific to Unet. But in general yes they are the same.